# repeating a table id while using foreach

Tags: javascript, html

My doubt is quite confusing. I'll break it down as simple as possible.
In HTML page I have a table inside a forEach loop. So multiple tables will occur. But all the tables has same header but rest of the values are different. So I need to set the table header in JavaScript to reduce the HTML code.

```
function myFunction()
{
   var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
   var header = table.createTHead();
   var row = header.insertRow(0);
   var cell = row.insertCell(0);
   cell.innerHTML = "<b>Resource Name</b>";
}
```

This is the code I have used. But id doesn't repeat again. So the table header is only coming for first table.
Any solutions or alternatives for id ?

Comment: You should be aware that it is invalid HTML to have multiple elements with the same `id`

Comment: @freefaller .Yea.. That's why I'm asking for an alternative

Comment: Perhaps create some HTML and CSS on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Add the code you have been trying so that we have a reference to the problem that you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
var len = tables.length, i=0, header, row, cell;
for(;i<len;i++){
   header = tables[i].createTHead();
   row = header.insertRow(0);
   cell = row.insertCell(0);
   cell.innerHTML = "<b>Resource Name</b>";
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/4AmmP/1/

**Edit** *(Using `class`)*

Add `class` to the tables you want to get affected (say `class="myTableClass"`) and use the below edited code

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
var len = tables.length, i=0, header, row, cell;
for(;i<len;i++){
  /* Check if the table has the class "myTable" */
  if(tables[i].className === "myTable") {
     header = tables[i].createTHead();
     row = header.insertRow(0);
     cell = row.insertCell(0);
     cell.innerHTML = "<b>Resource Name</b>";
  }
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/4AmmP/2/

Comment: I agree with you. But one problem is that I have another table in the same page which I don't want get affected.

Comment: @smashIT, if jQuery is an option to you then you could give them a `class` name and use `$(".tableclass")`

Comment: @rps. so, as code line number 4 says, class name for table is must. I'll try this

Comment: @rps. I tried it with a single table. But it seems not working. Here's the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4AmmP/)

Comment: It was `getElementsByTagName("table")` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("table")` in the code :)... I have edited the answer and added the fiddles